Time of allah in quran?
In 22:47 quran says a day of allah is a thousand man years. Does this mean allah experiences time and is part of creation ? Time is a part of the universe and cannot exist without it.

It is also said that the world (or universe?) was created in seven days, at a time when time itself was not created yet. Asking about time is always difficult, and science has not worked out what it really is. In a scientific way, it has to do with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Causality (A is because of B) but in view of quantum mechanics there are doubts if this really exists or if it is just part of how human thinking works.

Source ? As far as I know time is one of four dimensions. Just as space came into existence with the big bang so did time. Here's a quote from a BBC article It's tempting to ask what happened before this, but most physicists will say this is meaningless. "Time only exists as the Universe exists," says astrophysicist Emma Osborne at the University of York in the UK. "The moment the Universe came into existence is when time started.

"It's tempting to ask what happened before ... " eh, now, what before? How can there be a "before" before time was created (or came into existence)? This is just another example of how humans think and speak comes in conflict with time. Locally, time is just one of 4 dimensions, right, but globally it is far more complicated. I'd be glad to understand more of it, but I wasn't around at the time when time was born.

If you do have an urge for a better understanding of spacetime, have a look at Lorentz transformations, then general relativity and differential geometry.

This doesn't answer my question tho. For now I must rely on the opinions of experts
